# Transform iterative function into recursive function

Tags: python, loops, recursion, iteration

```
def solowayAverage():
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    while number != 99999:
        if (number >= 0):
            sum += number
            count += 1
        number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print("The average is: ", sum / count)
#iterative code

solowayAverage()

def solowayaveragerec(n, sum, count):
    if n !=99999 and n>0:
        sum += n
        count += 1
    else:
    return  solowayaveragerec(n, sum, count)

number = int(input("Give me a number: "))
solowayaveragerec(number, 0, 0)
#recursive code non completed
```

I would need help to make the recursive code work. The problem is that I don't know where to insert the call for the function in the recursive part

Comment: what exactly your purpose of this program? what is expected input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the recursive call with the new number added to the sum and the count added with 1:

```
def solowayaveragerec(sum=0, count=0):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if number == 99999:
        print("The average is: ", sum / count)
    else:
        solowayaveragerec(sum + number, count + 1)

solowayaveragerec()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PrimeSadClosedsource